# Decoding json with changing value type in Swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm creating a register view on my app, and I'm trying to decode a json but the key has a different type depending of the response.

If the register success:

```
{
    "data": true,
    "success": true
}
```

if the register fails with many reasons:

```
{
    "data": ["email is not valid", "password must have more than 4 digits"],
    "success": false
}
```

if the register fails with only one reason:

```
{
    "data": "email is not valid",
    "success": false
}
```

How to build a struct in Swift to handle this situations ?

```
struct Response: Codable {
   var data: // what type to use: String? [String]? Bool?
   var success: Bool
}
```

I asked the backend dev but for the moment, there's no changes on the backside, so I have to do with it ...

Comment: You can use a enum with associated value, or override `init(with decoder)` to have only "One String" (by combining when it's a `[String]`, "Ok", when it's `true`, etc. What do you want to do with the final value?

Comment: @Larme sorry I didn't understand about override and "ok" value. For the end of your comment, I will show the final value on popup like "you're now registered" if success= true, or "this email is already registered" if success = false

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes typo. fixed.

Comment: I think the first comment regarding using and enum is correct, the problem is you can't decode it based on other attribute, so you have to do a `try/catch` or a `try?` until you get what you need, and in that case add a special case enum `invalid` so you know everything failed when trying to decode it.

Comment: If you genuinely receive different data types, use Any.

Comment: @gnasher729 You can't use `Any` as a type with `Codable`

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce an enumeration with all possible options and provide your custom implementation of init(from decoder: Decoder)

```
enum DataType: Codable {
    case success(Bool)
    case singleError(String)
    case multiError([String])
    case undefined
}

struct Response: Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
        case success
    }

    var data: DataType
    var success: Bool

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
    
        if let bool = try? container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .data) {
            data = DataType.success(bool)
        } else if let string = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .data) {
            data = DataType.singleError(string)
        } else if let strings = try? container.decode([String].self, forKey: .data) {
            data = DataType.multiError(strings)
        } else {
            data = .undefined
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can just have separate properties in your struct and set them accordingly. Enum just looks more Swifty.

In case you can ignore Bool as Joakim suggested, then you can simply have that (no need for enum):

```
struct Response: Codable {
    
    var data: [String]
    var success: Bool

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
    
        if let string = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .data) {
            data = [string]
        } else if let strings = try? container.decode([String].self, forKey: .data) {
            data = strings
        } else {
            data = []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to decode the second property into a Bool, if success is true then data is always true.

Answer (score 0):

I would define an enum for this result. E.g.,

```swift
enum ResponseResult<Success> {
    case success(Success)
    case failure([String])
}
```

And I would then have a custom decoder for this:

```swift
struct ResponseObject<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let result: ResponseResult<T>
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data, success
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
        if success {
            result = .success(try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .data))
            return
        }
        
        if !container.contains(.data) {
            result = .failure([])
        } else if let message = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .data) {
            result = .failure([message])
        } else if let messages = try? container.decode([String].self, forKey: .data) {
            result = .failure(messages)
        } else if let wasNull = try? container.decodeNil(forKey: .data), wasNull {
            result = .failure([])
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .data, in: container, debugDescription: "Expected string, array of strings, null, or no key named 'data'")
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you mentioned this as being for this particular endpoint, that returned `Bool` upon success. But if they’ve done this for the registration endpoint, I bet they’ve done this for other endpoints, too. So, the above is generic, which in this case, you would use like:

```swift
let registrationResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject<Bool>.self, from: data)

switch registrationResponse.result {
case .success(let payload):
    print(payload)
case .failure(let messages):
    print(messages.joined(separator: " ")) 
}
```

But it could easily be used with other `Success` payload types.

Note, in this case, you probably don’t care about the `success` payload (i.e., if the registration was successful, then both the `success` and `data` keys are likely `true`; if it wasn’t successful, then the `data` will contain the error messages), but that is a conversation between you and your backend engineers. But you probably want the “let me extract the payload” pattern for those other endpoints where this inconsistent error message pattern is employed.

For more information about this custom decoding pattern, see [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).